# How do you mount sibling containers volumes started from another container?

Tags: docker

I am using docker for my dev environment: I have a dev image and I mount my source files as a volume.

But then I wanted to do the same on my continuous integration server (gitlab ci) and I carefully read docker doc's reference to https://jpetazzo.github.io/2015/09/03/do-not-use-docker-in-docker-for-ci/ but the solution of bind-mounting docker's unix socket into a docker client container makes impossible mounting volumes from it.

So basically my question is how would you solve this (given I am in a docker ci server/runner): I need to run the following command from a container (a gitlab runner).

```
$ git clone ... my-sources && cd my-sources
$ docker run my-dev-image -v $PWD:$PWD -w $PWD gcc main.c
```

Because obviously, the volume is taken from docker's "native" host and not the current container.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that your CI server is started with a volume (e.g. `docker run --name gitlabci -v /src gitlabci …`), then, when you start the other containers, start them with `docker run --volumes-from gitlabci …`. That way, `/src` will also be available in those containers, and whatever you put in this directory (from the CI server) will be available in the other containers.

Comment: so you don't give up saying "use dind" :-p ? The main drawback is that this solution is no longer transparent under a CI environment: I need to change `docker run` commands adding `--volumes-from ci-server`. While using `dind` or a native CI server (i.e., outside docker) allows 100% transparency/portability of my commands under the CI server.

Answer (score 1):

Way I've solved this is making sure that build paths are SAME on host and CI container. e.g - starting container with `-v /home/jenkins:/home/jenkins`. This way we have volume mounted from host to CI container. You can change to whatever directory you like, just making sure that `jenkins` user's home is set to that directory.

Note: I'm using jenkins as example, but any CI will work with same principle